# searching youtube video

Tags: youtube-api

How do I search for "python tutorial" videos on youtube? I get a lot of unrelated search results. What I need to know is the list of the users who have uploaded python related videos those are more than 20 minutes long.

Update:

In other words I need to scrap the following URL and find the unique users, for e.g. by PythonItalia

http://www.youtube.com/results?search_type=videos&search_category=28&search_duration=long&search_query=title%3Apython&page=10

Does it support NOT operator? so that I can exclude a user or category?

Comment: preferably shell script or PHP

Comment: You should really be using the [YouTube API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol) for this.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this with your API_KEY and YOUR_REGION:

https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=id,snippet&key=API_KEY&type=video&regionCode=YOUR_REGION&q=python+tutorial&maxResults=2

as for {API_KEY}, it's enabled here, in the [API console's](https://code.google.com/apis/console/)
if you registered your app. If not so you have to.

as for {YOUR_REGION}, look and choose [here](http://www.iso.org/iso/country_codes/iso_3166_code_lists/country_names_and_code_elements.htm)

In general, everything is described [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list)

I'm working on this as well :-)